# C# did not accepting checked property

Tags: c#, checked

```
try
    {
        DataRowView drv = attDataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        att_id = Convert.ToInt32(drv.Row[0].ToString());
        attComboBox.SelectedItem = drv.Row[1].ToString();
        rdata = drv.Row[2].ToString(); ;
        attDetail.Text = drv.Row[4].ToString();
        DateTime sdt = dc.changeDateG(drv.Row[3].ToString());

        if(rdata.Equals("حاضر"))
        {
                attPre.Checked = true;
        }
        else {
                attUp.Checked = true;
        }

        try
        {
            attDate.SelectedDate = sdt;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sdt.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch(NullReferenceException)
    {

    }
```

I am trying to set my attPre radio button checked but visual studio takes it as error any idea how to deal with this error???

Comment: should be --> `attPre.Checked = true;`

Comment: yes i know but the same problem again!!!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @sybren the ToggleButton.Cheked only appears on left hand side of += or -=

Comment: and when I'm using == the error become like this {Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: `Checked = true`  should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to deal with it

```
RadioButton pr = attPre as RadioButton;
                pr.IsChecked = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you doing comparision not assignment

Use this:
`attPre.Checked = true;`

Instead of
`attPre.Checked == true;`

Comment: Please post complete code, then only we can understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: Ok i will post it

Comment: yep you are right and I have find out the solution, thanks